# Interspace between text Lines in React native

Tags: text, react-native

I need to change the space between lines in a text in a React Native for both android and iOS.
This is the code in the styles pages:

```
text: {
  color: '#C0C0C0',
  fontSize: 18,
  textAlign: 'justify',
}
```

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use `lineHeight` -

```js
  text: {
    color: '#C0C0C0',
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'justify',
    lineHeight: 30,
  },
```

Comment: Note that nested Text components do not seem to inherit the lineHeight

Comment: Thank's nice solution instead of writing a custom text component.

Comment: It didnt work in my case of button.Help Please

Comment: `lineHeight` is terrible for accessibility. To demonstrate, try using `lineHeight` prop, and then go to your iPhone simulator's Settings > Accessibility > Display & Text Size > Larger Text, then go see how bad the text looks in your React Native app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
{'\n'}
```

inside your Text tag

example :

```
<Text>{'\n'} Heading : </Text>
```